# Unable to pass parameters into table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am able to create a new post that can pass the post parameters that will associate a new post to the current_user and feeling_ids.

However, at the same time, when the new post is created, I want to also associate the feeling_ids and current_user together in the user_feeling table. Feelings and users has a has_many :through association.

So far, I am able to build the new row whereby the user_id is entered, but unable to pass/enter the array of feeling_ids into the user_feeling table.

Any thoughts on how I can do this? Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at this.

```
    From: /Users/shengyeong/Desktop/emotion/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb @ line 19 PostsController#create:

        18: def create
     => 19:   binding.pry
        20:   @post = Post.new(post_params)
        21:   @post.creator = current_user
        22:   @user = current_user.user_feelings.build(params.require(:post).permit(feeling_id: params[:feeling_ids]))
        23:   if @post.save && @user.save
        24:     @post.create_activity :create, owner: current_user #from Public Activity gem. Using Common in Post Model.
        25:     flash[:notice] = "Your post was created."
        26:     redirect_to posts_path
        27:   else
        28:     render :new
        29:   end
        30: end 

    [1] pry(#<PostsController>)> @user = current_user.user_feelings.build(params.require(:post).permit(feeling_id: params[:feeling_ids]))
    Unpermitted parameters: feeling_ids, description, url
    => #<UserFeeling id: nil, user_id: 5, feeling_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    [2] pry(#<PostsController>)> @user = current_user.user_feelings.build(feeling_id: params[:feeling_ids])
    => #<UserFeeling id: nil, user_id: 5, feeling_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
    [3] pry(#<PostsController>)> @user = current_user.user_feelings.build(params.require(:post).permit(feeling_ids: [])
    [3] pry(#<PostsController>)* )  
    Unpermitted parameters: description, url
    ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: feeling_ids
    from /Users/shengyeong/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activerecord-4.1.6/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:50:in `rescue in _assign_attribute'
    [4] pry(#<PostsController>)> params
    => {"utf8"=>"✓",
     "authenticity_token"=>"CNBz5r/549wuGjwm45KlNs38hVCASc5nemUatpVedYY=",
     "post"=>{"feeling_ids"=>["3", ""], "description"=>"I hope this works.",       "url"=>"www.hopes.com"},
     "commit"=>"Create Post",
     "action"=>"create",
     "controller"=>"posts"}


      def post_params
        params.require(:post).permit(:url, :description, feeling_ids: [])
      end
```

**UPDATE: ADDED MODELS FOR REVIEW**

```
class UserFeeling < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :feeling
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_feelings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :feelings, through: :user_feelings
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :creator, foreign_key: 'user_id', class_name: 'User'
  has_many :post_feelings
  has_many :feelings, through: :post_feelings
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end

class Feeling < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_feelings
  has_many :posts, through: :post_feelings
  has_many :user_feelings, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :user_feelings  
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `params.require(:post).permit(feeling_id: params[:feeling_ids])` to build user_feelings

Comment: Can you paste your user, feeling and user_feeling model?

Comment: Hey Tony, thanks for the reply. Yeah, I am concerned it could be bad coding practice. But anyways, I have attached the models. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you want to associate feelings with current_user? If so, why do you pass feeling_ids in?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do that. feelings_id was passed in reaction to the output of the params from binding pry. Perhaps it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have many-to-many association, you should use associated model(Feeling) directly instead of the middle relationship model(UserFeeling) in most cases. Rails provides many methods to achieve this: [has-many-association-reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference).

In your case, you can use **collection=objects**:

```
# Just pass ids of feeling you need in
feeling_ids = params[:post][:feeling_ids]
feelings = Feeling.where(id: feeling_ids)
current_user.feelings = feelings
```

or just **collection_singular_ids=ids**:

```
feeling_ids = params[:post][:feeling_ids]
current_user.feeling_ids = feeling_ids
```

(These snippets are just examples, which you can refer to)

Both methods will *make the collection contain only the supplied objects, by adding and deleting as appropriate*.

Comment: Thanks. Helped breakthrough the mental barrier in getting this working. Lets just say if every time a new status and its associating feeling is created, I just want to add more entries rather than adding the new and deleting the old. How can this be done?

Comment: What's new status? Do you mean you want to create new feelings in the same action?

Comment: Sorry, I meant post. 

With the codes you have provided, I am replacing the old feelings. However, I would like to add the new feelings. For example,

Currently there is User_id = 1 with feeling_id = 4 in the user_feelings table. Using your code, when user_id 1 add a new post with new feelings of feeling_id 4 and 1, the old feeling_id 4 will be replace by 4 and 1 with total_count of feelings being 2. I would instead want user_id 1 to have feeling_ids of 4, 4 and 1 with total_count of feelings being 3.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this.It seems your requirement is a little strange.But you can calculate the total_count through posts.Try `user.posts.map(&:feeling_count).sum`.

Comment: Tony, I am still learning how to properly design a good app. =)
So where do I put 'user.posts.map(&:feeling_count).sum' ?

Comment: Put where you want to get count of feeling.

Comment: Was not able to resolve through my method, but your help made me rethink the design of the app and do it through a better way. Thanks. Will relook at it and see how to change it.